# What is the purpose of the two variables Global`args and Global`dims

Tags: system-variables

When opening the mma, I find that two variables `` Global`args `` and `` Global`dims `` have been defined. One can check them by running `` ?Global`* `` .
What is the purpose of the two variables? 
When I load other packages, there is a warning "Symbol args appears in multiple contexts". Is the variable `args` a special variable ?